# I'm trying to install steam on debian jessie/sid but I'm getting unresolved dependencies

Tags: debian, steam

I'm following the debian wiki on installing steam but I keep getting dependency issues.

Debian tells me to edit my sources.list to:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

My sources.list looks like this:

Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid \n \l

```
#
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

#deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian wheezy main

#deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
#deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
```

My unresolved dependencies look like:

```
 Keep the following packages at their current version:          
1)      gcc-4.8-base:i386 [Not Installed]                            
2)      libc6:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
3)      libc6-i686:i386 [Not Installed]                              
4)      libdrm-intel1:i386 [Not Installed]                           
5)      libdrm-nouveau2:i386 [Not Installed]                         
6)      libdrm-radeon1:i386 [Not Installed]                          
7)      libdrm2:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
8)      libelf1:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
9)      libexpat1:i386 [Not Installed]                               
10)     libffi6:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
11)     libgcc1:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
12)     libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 [Not Installed]                         
13)     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [Not Installed]                         
14)     libglapi-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                           
15)     libllvm3.3:i386 [Not Installed]                              
16)     libpciaccess0:i386 [Not Installed]                           
17)     libstdc++6:i386 [Not Installed]                              
18)     libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 [Not Installed]                       
19)     libx11-6:i386 [Not Installed]                                
20)     libx11-xcb1:i386 [Not Installed]                             
21)     libxau6:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
22)     libxcb-dri2-0:i386 [Not Installed]                           
23)     libxcb-glx0:i386 [Not Installed]                             
24)     libxcb1:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
25)     libxdamage1:i386 [Not Installed]                             
26)     libxdmcp6:i386 [Not Installed]                               
27)     libxext6:i386 [Not Installed]                                
28)     libxfixes3:i386 [Not Installed]                              
29)     libxxf86vm1:i386 [Not Installed]                             
30)     steam:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
31)     zlib1g:i386 [Not Installed]                                  

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                   
32)     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 recommends libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
```

I think this could be something to do with `# dpkg --add-architecture i386` but nothing seems to happen when I run the command.

Help appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
root@Wheezy:/# apt-get install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.12) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Edit:**

```
root@Wheezy:/# dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
root@Wheezy:/# dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

**Edit:**

```
     root@Wheezy:/# apt-cache policy libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386  libx11-6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 steam:i386
libc6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.18-4
  Version table:
     2.18-4 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
libstdc++6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.8.2-16
  Version table:
     4.8.2-16 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
libx11-6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:1.6.2-1
  Version table:
     2:1.6.2-1 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.2.2-1
  Version table:
     9.2.2-1 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.2.2-1
  Version table:
     9.2.2-1 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0~git20131104-1.1
  Version table:
     0~git20131104-1.1 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
steam:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.0.45-1
  Version table:
     1.0.0.45-1 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free i386 Packages
root@Wheezy:/#
```

**Edit:**

```
root@Wheezy:/# apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.uk.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: So are you not able to install those packages with `apt-get libc6:i386` and so on?

Comment: @user4186 I get another error installing gcc unmet dependencies. I upgraded from wheezy fairly recently to install steam, maybe this is causing problems?

Comment: @UzumakiDev you dropped off. Try installing those the dependencies `apt-get` complained about individually. E.g. starting with `apt-get install libc6:i386`.

Comment: For the record, @derobert and I spent some time trying to help the poster in chat. This class of problems is usually resolvable, but not in this case. Eventually the poster re-installed. Since this problem is now no longer reproducible, closing is the right thing to do here.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks for the help :) I probably did something when I upgraded from wheezy to jessie. I reinstalled Debian, stayed on wheezy and adjusted the steam sources list.